# Constant sheaves associated with locally closed subsets

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

I'm studying P. Schapira's notes *Algebra and Topology*, available online [here](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~schapira/lectnotes/), and I'm having trouble understanding sheaves associated with locally closed subsets, in particular constant sheaves.

For example, the following is Exercise 5.5:

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $Y = \mathbb{R}$, $S = \{(x, y) \in X \mid x y \ge 1 \}$, and let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be the map $(x, y) \mapsto y$. Calculate $f_* k_{XS}$.

Unravelling the definitions, I see that for $U \subseteq Y$ open,
$$ (f_* k_{XS})(U) = k_{XS} (\mathbb{R}\times U) = (i_{S*} i_S^{-1} k_X) (\mathbb{R} \times U) = (i_S^{-1} k_X) ((\mathbb{R} \times U)\cap S)$$
but here I'm stuck. The problem is that I don't really know how to deal with the functor $i_S^{-1}$ (unless it appears in a context where I can use the adjunction $i_S^{-1} \dashv i_{S*}$).

I'd be really grateful if someone could help me solve the above exercise, and maybe give me some insight on how to handle this kind of problems in general. Thank you.

Comment: You are doing fine - $(i^{-1}_Sk_X)((\mathbb{R} \times U \cap S)$ is fine. Now consider two cases: if U is an small interval containing $0$, or if it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I understand. If $U$ is an interval and $0 \in U$ then $V = (\mathbb{R} \times U) \cap S$ has two connected components, $V_1$ and $V_2$, so I can write $(i_S^{-1} k_X)(V) = (i_S^{-1}k_X)(V_1) \oplus (i_S^{-1}k_X)(V_2)$; otherwise $V = V_1$ is connected. In both cases $(i_S^{-1} k_X)(V_i) = k$ because any locally constant function on a connected set is constant. Am I right?

Comment: yes, that's correct.